# Can I restrict a user from accessing my gitlab repo but giving read/write access

Tags: gitlab

Can I give a user read/write access to my repo using some app like [prose](https://github.com/prose/prose) or [netliy-cms](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms) (without netlify hosting) but restrict from accessing my repo?

Answer (score 0):

GitLab repo visibility is tied to the git repo, you cannot change them independently.

What you could do is use a secondary/service account for your Prose/Netlify-cms to access your repo, while keeping it private.

Comment: Please explain what you meant by secondary/service account

Comment: Let's say you have your usual account, the one you use for working with your repos. This secondary account would be configured to have permissions on your private (to restrict access to your repo) repo so something like https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends#gitlab-backend would work.

Comment: I think I tried it already. I am using the method gitlab implicit grant that in your given link. I have a usual account with repo access. And I create another gitlab account. From first account I go to settings > members, and added second account there and gave maintainer permission role. But the problem is when I login to second account I can see my repo in the second account.

Comment: Hi, do you have any suggestions?